# insert delay in jmeter in capturing results

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter script which does a remote ssh and executes a R script now I need the jmeter to delay wherein it starts capturing results in the listeners after say  6 seconds how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do it using JMeter Test Elements however you can insert a delay on SSH command level using [sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) command like:

```
./your_R_Script && sleep 6
```

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) for more tips and tricks on how to kick off remote processes from JMeter